# Echo HTML with PHP inside

Tags: php, html

Please help me turn this into dynamic using echo with HTML and PHP using array range

```
    <?php
       $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
       $selected='<img src="assets/images/resev.png" class="img-circle" width="40" height="40" />';
       $aval='<img src="assets/images/aval.png" class="img-circle" width="40" height="40" />';
       foreach ($arr as &$value) {
        <button class="btn btn-default" id=$value <?php if (isset($_SESSION['buttons']) && (in_array($value, $_SESSION['buttons']))){ ?> disabled <?php   } ?> >
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['buttons']) && (in_array($value, $_SESSION['buttons']))) {
         echo $selected ;
        }
        else {
          echo $aval ;
        }
      ?>$value
    </button>
```

so far I have done this

```
<?php
  $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
  foreach ($arr as &$value) {
      echo '<button class="btn btn-default" id='. $value if (isset($_SESSION['buttons']) && (in_array($value, $_SESSION['buttons']))){ disabled }. '> //line 84
      </button>' ;
  }
?>
```

and I'm already getting

> Parse error: parse error in xyz.php on line 84

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing html and php variables inside an echo statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271501/mixing-html-and-php-variables-inside-an-echo-statement)

Comment: Search on Google you will find many answers given already.

Comment: @AmiteshKumar  tried , nothing helped :(

Comment: @AmiteshKumar also can you explain why im getting the parse error ?

Comment: `...$value if...` missing `;` , `disabled` shoud be `echo "disabled"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in following way -

```
<?php
  $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
  foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $disabled = '';
    if(isset($_SESSION['buttons']) && (in_array($value, $_SESSION['buttons']))) {
        $disabled = 'disabled';
    }  
    echo '<button class="btn btn-default" id='.$value.' '.$disabled.'>Test Button</button>' ;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid such problems and errors in future you must separate your code for blocks:

1. Define values
2. Calculate dynamic values
3. Include template
4. Evaluate template

Like this:

index.php contents

```
<?php

// define
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = null; // value for fallback

// calculate
$c = $a + $b;

// include template
include_once 'template.phtml';
```

template.phtml contents (evaluate template)

```
<div>
    <p><?= $a ?></p>
    <p><?= $b ?></p>
    <?php if ($c !== null) { ?>
        <p><?= $c ?></p>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p>$c variable has not calculated</p>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can call an if statement inside your echo function call, you need to seperate them from each others, something to try could be this:

```
echo '<button class=\"btn btn-default\" id='. $value;
if (isset($_SESSION['buttons']) && (in_array($value, $_SESSION['buttons']))) 
{
  echo 'disabled';
} 
echo '></button>' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining html and php using echo statements can quickly become messy and unreadable.

Read up on the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and also on the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). Applying both conventions, your code would look more like this:

```
<?php
    $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
    foreach ($arr as &$value) : ?>
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="<?=$value;?><?=((isset($_SESSION['buttons']) && (in_array($value, $_SESSION['buttons'])))?' disabled':''?>">
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['buttons']) && (in_array($value, $_SESSION['buttons']))) : ?>
            <img src="assets/images/resev.png" class="img-circle" width="40" height="40" />
        <?php else : ?>
            <img src="assets/images/aval.png" class="img-circle" width="40" height="40" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    </button>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The parse error is a result of your attempt to chain an if statement ($value if...) with an echo statement, and also just having `disabled` instead of `echo 'disabled'` in your if {} statement.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

Working code:

```
       <?php
          $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
          foreach ($arr as &$value) {
            $disabled = '';
            if(isset($_SESSION['buttons']) && (in_array($value, $_SESSION['buttons']))) {
                $disabled = 'disabled';
                $image = $selected ;
            }
            else {
              $disabled = '';
              $image = $aval ;
            }
            echo '<button class="btn btn-default" id='.$value.' '.$disabled.'>'
            .$image.' '.$value.'</button>' ;
          }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from readability, the issue can be fixed like this:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    echo '<button class="btn btn-default" id="'. $value  . '" ' . ((isset($_SESSION['buttons']) && in_array($value, $_SESSION['buttons'])) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '') . '>test</button>';
}
```

Here I used what's known as a `ternary operator`.

Here's it, but a bit clearer:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    echo '<button class="btn btn-default" id="'. $value  . '"
    ' . (
            (isset($_SESSION['buttons']) && in_array($value, $_SESSION['buttons']))
                ? 'disabled="disabled"' : ''
        ) . '
    >test</button>';
}
```

A ternary operator is similar to an if statement, but is commonly used for inline things.

The syntax is this:

```
$myVar = (expression ? true : false);
```

Here's an example of how to get "Woo!" when a number is 1.

```
$number = 1;
$wooOrNe = ($number === 1 ? "Woo!" : "Ne."); // Woo!
```