# Change backgroundcolor with if statement in PHP

Tags: php

If time2 is bigger than time 1 I want the background color change to red.
I'm a totally noob in this and I tried now for days but not getting it to work.
In CSS I have `.bgred {background: red;}`

```
<?php
$sql = ("SELECT name, time1, time2 FROM myTable WHERE dates LIKE '".$_POST['dat']."' ");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);        

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {     

    echo "<table action='' method='POST'><tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Time1</th>
    <th>Time2</th></tr>";

    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $var1 = $row["time1"];
        $var2 = $row["time2"];
        if($var2 < $var1) {
            $bgred = 'class="bgred"';
        } else {
            $bgred = '';
        }

        echo "<tr><td>".$row["name"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["time1"]."</td>
        <td class="$bgred">".$row["time2"]."</td></tr>";
        }
    }

    echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39444025/3558278

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$bgred = null;
$rows = null;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {     


    $var1 = $row["time1"];
    $var2 = $row["time2"];
    if($var2 < $var1) {
        $bgred = 'class="bgred"';       
    } else {
        $bgred = '';
    }

    $rows .=  '<tr>
                  <td>' . $row["name"] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $row["time1"] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $row["time2"] . '</td>
             </tr>';
}  

echo '<table action="" method="POST">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Time1</th>
            <th class="' . $bgred . '">Time2</th>
        </tr>
        ' . $rows . '
    </table>';
```

Do you have a reason to use double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

You are not echoing out $bgred anywhere.

```
<?php
$sql = ("SELECT name, time1, time2 FROM myTable WHERE dates LIKE '".$_POST['dat']."' ");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

echo "<table action='' method='POST'><tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Time1</th>
<th>Time2</th></tr>";

// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {     


    $var1 = $row["time1"];
    $var2 = $row["time2"];

//edited here
    if(strtotime($var2) < strtotime($var1)) {
        $bgred = 'bgred'; 
//done with edit      
    } else {
        $bgred = '';
    }

    echo "<tr><td class='$bgred'>".$row["name"]."</td>
    <td class='$bgred'>".$row["time1"]."</td>
    <td class='$bgred'>".$row["time2"]."</td></tr>";       
    }       
}       

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn); ?>
```

Comment: I edited  my post. I have <td class="$bgred">".$row["time2"]."</td></tr>";        
But it still not working

Comment: If you view source do the right ones have the class=bgred?  Also in your css try background-color: red;

Comment: Also what type of field is time in your database?  timestamp, date, etc?  Edited answer to convert to unix time before comparing

Comment: The fields are timestamps

Comment: I had an error.  I was setting bgred = 'class="bgred"'.  Made a change to just set it to bgred = 'bgred'  Should work now.

Comment: Is there any way to change format so it´s only show the time and not the date? I use timestamp because otherwise it´s not show "red" if time goes over midnight.

Comment: $var1 = date('g:i A', $row["time1"]);
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for how ever you want to format it.