# How to add Html code inside php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to create a button, which downloads a file, and this file is created based on php variables.
The "instruction" to show this html code is inside a php file.

So far, I've got this ( don´t think it's ok ):

Inside the php this generates an email:

```
    $addressforics = get_valueFromStringUrl($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'address');

    ob_start();
    <form method="post" action="/download-ics.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="date_start" value="2017-1-16 9:00AM">
      <input type="hidden" name="date_end" value="2017-1-16 10:00AM">
      <input type="hidden" name="location" value=$addressforics>
      <input type="hidden" name="description" value="This is my description">
      <input type="hidden" name="summary" value="This is my summary">
      <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://example.com">
      <input type="submit" value="Add to Calendar">
    </form>
    $my_var = ob_get_clean();
```

How to insert the php variable `$addressforics` into the HTML code ( which is inside the same php code, where `$addressforics` is defined )?

Comment: I am talking about this line:
      <input type="hidden" name="location" value=$addressforics>

Comment: Your question is very unclear. This code doesnt even look like it will execute; how are you telling the server which is PHP and which is HTML? There's no tags at all.

Comment: Hi, this is not the full code. Its just part of a php file.
I am not a programmer, I am just trying to add a feature to a wordpress plugin

Comment: Could you go into more detail about your issue and confirm if Adrian's solution actually solves your issue? You're advised to follow the [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question.

Comment: This was my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271501/mixing-html-and-php-variables-inside-an-echo-statement

Answer (score 3):

You have to write the php code between `<?php and ?>`, as documented [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Something like..

```
<?php
$addressforics = get_valueFromStringUrl($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'address');

ob_start();
?>
<form method="post" action="/download-ics.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="date_start" value="2017-1-16 9:00AM">
  <input type="hidden" name="date_end" value="2017-1-16 10:00AM">
  <input type="hidden" name="location" value="<?php echo $addressforics; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="description" value="This is my description">
  <input type="hidden" name="summary" value="This is my summary">
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://example.com">
  <input type="submit" value="Add to Calendar">
</form>
<?php
$my_var = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot. Fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

to write php value into html element

```
<input name="test" value="<?php echo $a ; ?> ">
```

or

```
<?php echo "<input name='test' value='".$a."'>"; ?>
```